# Laravel Eloquent - Lazy load fails with select constrain

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Im trying to select specific columns from the main model table while using lazy load later. But it seems to not find the relationship if i add select to the query.
Could not find anyone else listing this problem. Also a note this list of columns that i want to select is dynamic so i want to change the columns selected on the fly , so i cannot specify visible / hidden in the model itself.

```
class SignatureDoc
{
    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class,'clients_hash');
    }
}
```

when i  run query like this:

```
SignatureDoc::where('hash',$hash)->get()->first()->client;
```

i do get client model without any issues.
However when i add specific columns to select:

```
SignatureDoc::select('name','hash')->where('hash',$hash)->get()->first()->client;
```

i get null as a result.

i assume select constrains the lazy load, so i even tried:

```
SignatureDoc::select('name')->with('client')->where('hash',$hash)->get()->first()->client;
```

with no success. Should i specify something inside select?

same happens if i move coulmns inside get() like so ->get([$columns]);

Comment: Check the output of `SignatureDoc::select('name')->with('client')->where('hash',$hash)->get()->first()` and check https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Comment: @Hisham yep, its giving null. i tried that too.

Comment: i know that example is eager loading not lazy loading. I just wanted to show that even with eager laoding eloquent does not let me use select() and keep relationship at the same time

Comment: is the column `name` ambiguous? Try prefixing the column names with table names like `client.name`

Comment: @Hisham nope, thats not it. If it was ambigious i would be getting an sql error, and im not. Im just getting null on the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `SignatureDoc` model to retrieve the `Client` it belongs to, it needs to have the `clients_hash` (the name of the foreign key provided for the `client()` relation).

Your select statement should include that column, otherwise the related client can not be found, since the column does not exist.

Update your select statement to include the `clients_hash`, and it should work.

**Example**

```
SignatureDoc::select('name', 'hash', 'clients_hash')
    ->where('hash', $hash)
    ->get()
    ->first()
    ->client;
```

Comment: yes that did the trick. thank u so much